# Load Office Add-In (Office Online Server) autoload

Tags: office-js

I am working with office-js and I want to autoload an Add-In for all my users.

I have Office Online Server installed, I don't have Sharepoint server. The Add-In is working fine and tested with Office 365.

Is it possible to autoload this plugin? How I can do it? Is there any alternative or options to accomplish this?

Comment: By "autoload", do you mean automatically open when a document opens? Or do you mean Centralized Deployment?

Comment: I think either can resolve my issue.

Comment: Hi @Vidal, how do your "Office Online Server" serve files (can it show and edit files that store in dropbox or googledrive?)

Comment: @haiduong87 you will have to write your own integration to serve the files to the WOPI server. Office Online Server is "Word" in the cloud, you need to have an API that communicate with it to read and write files (your server, or were you want them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy an add-in for a group without using AppSource or a SharePoint catalog, you can use Centralized Deployment. The details are described here: [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment). **UPDATE:** But this is not supported for Office Online Server.

If you want an add-in to automatically open when a document is opened, you can configure the document to do this. For details, see this article in the official docs: [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).

Comment: My friend thank you for your response I am trying to get this to work. Will get back to you as soon I got some feedback. Really appreciate your input

Comment: Centralized Deployment only works for Office 365, at the moment we are using Office Online Server on premises. Also the add-in is only for internal use so our users can't get them from the store and our IT director is not going to approve publishing it on the office store.

Comment: The word I get back from Microsoft experts is that there is nothing like Centralized Deployment that will work in OOS at this time.

Comment: Updated answer as requested.