# Sideload A Microsoft Word Add-In In Office Online Server

Tags: office-addins, word-addins, sideloading, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I'm working on a modern Word Add-In that we would like to work inside Word for the Web on Office Online Server (2019) via WOPI. For testing, we would like to sideload the Add-In. I can do this in the O365 version of Word for the Web without problems, but the only option on OOS appears to be loading Add-Ins from AppSource. I also understand from various (informal) posts that centralized deployment is not available in OOS. Does anyone know if it is possible to enable sideloading in OOS?

By sideloading, I mean manually uploading the manifest.xml file via the "Add-Ins" button on the ribbon bar. In O365 this option is called "Upload My Add-In".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible - see a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892361/1332034) answered by a Microsoft person.